# Saving a pavlova that didn't form a crust

Tags: baking, eggs, dessert, meringue

I have cooked my pavlova the same way I normally do, however it hasn't formed a nice crust like it usually does. I've heard that it may have something to do with the humidity? (It did rain here today and was a reasonably warm day.) Can I put it back in the oven and to save it or do I have to start all over again?

Comment: When you say it didn't form a crust - is it still wet and holding its shape, like a meringue topping? Or did it collapse or do something else entirely? What exactly does it look like?

Comment: What temperature and process did you use to cook it? if it has set,  shove it back in a very hot oven for a few minutes, and watch it. When it reaches the colour you like, take it out

Comment: Thanks, yes, held it's shape, so turned the oven back on to a higher heat (180deg C) and left it in for about 15mins watching it closely, let it cool again and it did form a crust but had collapsed about 20mins later....so I'll try again today :)

Answer (score 2):

I have never tried it myself,  but a torch can be used to make a crust on the meringue in a baked Alaska. Testing it on a small part of it could give you a clue if it is worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a good chance you can save it by extending the time in the oven and increasing the temperature slightly (if the humidity is the problem it means that it is loosing water slower so it needs more time and it can benefit from a temperature boost).

BUT IF IT IS CRITICAL that you get it right and you don't have time to do it again if this fails, assume it would fail. The crust may get too thick for your liking.

Comment: Thanks Ali, have another attempt in the oven at the moment. Here's hoping to success today :)