# New Oven - Bad Pavlova

Tags: oven

l always have had great success with pavlovas.  Recently l bought a new double oven.  l made a pavlova and put it in the small oven.  A complete disaster.  l made another and put it in the bigger oven - same thing.  The meringue was coming away from the sides and it was flat and soft.  Have tried another three times with the same result.  Is it the oven ? ? ?

Comment: Are you using an oven thermometer?

Comment: There are so many variables when baking, it's hard to say. It could be a change in humidity levels from last time you made it, oven calibration issues, etc. Have you tried to bake anything else?  Here are some other Pavlova question's that you might find useful: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10656/why-did-my-pavlova-not-bake-properly http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19917/saving-a-pavlova-that-didnt-form-a-crust http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9860/what-is-the-best-way-to-making-a-great-pavlova-base/9902#9902

Comment: Yes l have made other things in the oven with no problem at all.  Its just the pavlovas that are a failure.  l have never heard of anyone having this problem before.

Answer (score 2):

Your new oven might be off in temperature calibration.

Or your old oven might have been off in temperature calibration, but you were used to it - so you set the new oven where you set the old oven, and even if the new oven temperature is correct as set, it's not what the old one was when set there.

If there are other differences between the ovens (fuel source, convection fan or lack thereof, etc.) those may also play a role.

Comment: Its practically the same oven only a newer version.  l am not doing anything different with the pavlovas and yet they have all been a complete disaster,  Really so annoyed about it.

Comment: @Debs, ovens aren't precision instruments -- I wouldn't be surprised to find two copies of an identical model with a 25-50 degree variation in temperature.

Comment: Maybe l will try it again at a different temperature.